# Django modify FileField input button and label in Django form

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I am trying to get rid of the regular file upload view by default in a Django formset, my approach is right now to hide the input file and then use a label and make that label clickable to upload file, however, right now after clicking on my label nothing can be uploaded and the select file window does not pop up, I am using pure CSS for this current my html template is:

**HTML FORM**

```
<form method="POST" data-url="{% url 'home:post-create' %}" class="post-create-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" >Create a Post</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-y: auto;">
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="button" id="show-image-upload-inputs" class="btn btn-sm mr-auto btn-primary pb-1">
            <span><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></span>
        </button>
        <div id="image-upload-div" class="mt-1 mx-1" style="display: none;">

                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    {% for a_form in formset %}
                    <div class="pl-1">
                        <label for="file"><i class="mt-2 fas fa-plus fa-5x"></i></label>
                        {{ a_form }}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>


<style>
input[type='file'] {
    display: none;
}
label[for='file'] {
    padding-left: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(212, 231, 238);
    border: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color:lightblue;
}
</style>
```

**Django View**

```
@login_required
def post_create(request):
    data = dict()
    ImageFormset = modelformset_factory(Images,form=ImageForm,extra=4)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        formset = ImageFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():    
            post = form.save(False)
            post.author = request.user
            #post.likes = None
            post.save()
            for f in formset:
                try:
                    i = Images(posts=post, image=f.cleaned_data['image'])
                    i.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    break
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            posts = Post.objects.all()
            posts = Post.objects.order_by('-last_edited')
            data['posts'] = render_to_string('home/posts/home_post.html',{'posts':posts},request=request)
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = PostForm  
        formset = ImageFormset(queryset=Images.objects.none())     
    context = {
    'form':form,
    'formset':formset,
    }
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('home/posts/post_create.html',context,request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I was wondering how can I generally change FIleField in Django form? I want to use my current approachh and overide the labels created by Django form however I do not know if that is the right choice.

Comment: First this has nothing to do with Django or FileField. This is a HTML file input field. Second, what does "however, right now after clicking on my label can be uploaded" mean? What's the actual problem?

Answer (score 2):

Browsers usually prevent the file field from triggering when it is set to `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`, though there are tricks where you move the file field outside the view port using `position: fixed/absolute; left:-10000px` and trigger the file field using JS.

If you want to completely not use JS, you can use the following trick that uses HTML/CSS only:

```css
form {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
input {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;

    /* Your styling here */
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0095ff;
}

input:hover + label {
    background-color: #0065ad;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type='file' />
    <label>Upload File</label>
</form>
```

Basically you're covering your custom label with the file field, and making the file field transparent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. How can I set the FileField outside viewport, I should basically add a clickable action to a div and trigger it using JavaScript. Is that your suggestion for using javascript? @grandphuba

Comment: Thank you I am trying to implement that but the issue is i do not know the id of the input field generated by Django how can I trigger each input field when there are four fields in the formset? @grandphuba

Comment: Are you using jQuery (or some library) or just plain JS?

Comment: No, I am trying to do it with jQuery but I cannot manage to set the correct id of the forms, therefore, it is not working @grandphuba